# Start heat pump (HVAC) from electric generator: AVR voltage surge issue

Tags: heat, generator, over-voltage-protection, hvac

I'm trying to start the heat pump from the generator, and it turns out successfully...for an hour.

First of all, mandatory specs and preconditions:

- heat pump: Mitsubishi Electric PUHZ-SHW140YHA
- electric generator: Foro FV 20000 TRA 14 KW (alternator: NSM ZR 112 SD; AVR: NSM AVR960D)
- heat pump and the electric generator are three-phase
- heat pump and electric generator are connected to the electrical panel of the house, covered by voltage control relays (overvoltage protection), the upper threshold in all relays are set to 255 volts
- a device for monitoring the performance of the power grid has been installed, which allows you to monitor the values ​​of consumed current, power, voltage and other things in real time, save historical data

So, the heat pump did not work for three days, a complete "cold start" was performed. After a few hours of operation of the heat pump, all three voltage monitoring relays suddenly triggered. It turned out that the voltage was in the range of 269-272 volts, which greatly exceeds the upper permissible limit of 255 volts.

The heat pump, of course, turned off, and the electric generator continued to work without any problems. A minute later, I turned the heat pump back on and it continued to work successfully. But, after 15-20 minutes, everything repeated: the voltage rose to ~270 volts for a moment for all three phases, the pump turned off, and so on. And so it was a few more times, until I completely stopped the process.

What was done after:

1. Checking the generator for overload. The monitoring device helped here, it showed that the total load was about 4,000 watts, which does not really matter for a generator with a rated power of 14,000 watts.
2. Check for load spikes on the heat pump. The monitoring device is back in business. The values of voltage, current and power grew smoothly, there were no sharp upward jumps. However every 15-20 minutes, the heat pump, until then smoothly increasing its power, abruptly dropped it: the current consumption became near zero. Important: the same behavior of a heat pump - a smooth increase in load and a sharp drop in it - is also observed when working from a conventional power supply, and not just from an electric generator.

Then I put the pieces of the puzzle together and realized the essence of the problem.

A large and powerful generator has a large and powerful engine with a large and heavy flywheel with a large moment of inertia. When the load from the generator abruptly leaves - it was 4,000 watts, and in the next moment it became about 50 watts - the engine and flywheel does not have time to slow down, and the alternator continues to turn at high speeds. Which leads to a sharp voltage surge, due to which the voltage control relays are then triggered and turn off the current supply to the heat pump.

I tried to determine what are generally possible magnitudes of such power surges? Is ~270 volts the maximum possible value for this generator or it can be 290 volts, 320 volts or more?

I looking for the specification for installed AVR device and the following was indicated there:

> Voltage accuracy:
>
> ± 0.5% from no-load to rated load in steady state conditions, with
> any power factor and for frequency variations ranging from -5% to +20%
> of the rated value

Doing simple calculations:

1. Electric generator nominal output voltage is 230 volts, due to spec
2. 20% from 230 volts is 46 volts
3. 230 + 46 = 276 volts - the maximum voltage that the AVR can deliver. Matches what I got in practice...

The graphs from the monitoring device below illustrate the ongoing processes. Upper limit of 255 volts on voltage graph is inaccurate value: monitoring device turns off faster than it has time to record data about the voltage increased to ~270 volts:

[image]

The main question is what to do with it? Usually, all problems with starting HVAC equipment are related to the lack of a "soft start" in them and high inrush currents, but in my case, I need something like a "soft stop". I have already considered several options, but have not come up with a good solution:

1. I can't put voltage stabilizers on every phase, as it is generally accepted that the voltage stabilizers are very harmful to the electric generator. To a greater extent, it harms when the voltage drops, but also when it is exceeded too. Although I could be wrong, and perhaps there are some special stabilizers for this case.
2. I can't increase the upper voltage threshold on the voltage control relay to ~ 270 volts, as this will lead to the fact that sensitive equipment, especially LED lamps PSU, may be damaged.
   I would appreciate any help or advice.

Perhaps there are some devices that I can use to ensure that the load from the generator does not leave so abruptly? Or somehow adjust the heat pump itself?

Thank you.

Comment: For anyone else confused, it means "automatic voltage regulator."

Comment: Have you considered (as an experiment) adding a 1kW resistive heating element to each phase? Some background load may reduce the transients. Now if it works you don't want to burn a constant 3kW, but you may find some lower load may work, or you may find some use for it (water heater?) Or add a dump load at higher voltages (slightly below the existing trip)

Comment: @user_1818839 yes, the idea with an additional load also came to my mind: just yesterday I bought an electric heater 1.1 kW, and something else of similar power. I'll try to use it next time. But this solution does not look very technological and reliable, i think :)